# Eclipse (Java & Hibernate) Content Assistant Not Working

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm having a problem with Eclipse and the content assistant regarding Hibernate.

As far as I understand, I've linked the Javadoc for hibernate-core-4.0.0.CR7.jar correctly (the validation goes through).

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestHibernate
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.

}
```

Once I typed "config." however, I was not greeted with the content assistant. Can anyone offer some insight into what might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: If you remove the `config.line` that you're trying to auto-complete, does the code compile without error?  (You've successfully linked the Javadoc to the JAR, but is the JAR properly configured into the project?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing in a method body or an initialisation block.

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestHibernate
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    public void someMethod() {
        config. //Should work from here
    }

}
```